# New-PSsession to create a loop and wait to finish foreach line in text file

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get files from servers in a list using the below

```
$server = Get-Content server.txt
$server| ForEach-Object {
$session=new-pssession -computername $server -credential (Import-Clixml "mycredentials.xml")
Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock ${function:getfiles}
Copy-Item -path "C:\some\folder\*" -Destination "C:\localfolder" -recurse -FromSession $session
}
```

If I supply explicitly a name in -computername, works like a charm.
When there are several names in the list, the execution stops after the first one. I suspect that the session closes after the first execution.

Is there a way to make it like this:

get-content -> for each line execute the copy-item -> close session -> open new session to new server -> .....etc, meaning that $session will be only for the current server.

$function:getfiles

```
function getfiles {
New-Item -Force -Path C:\path\trace.txt
$remoteserver=$env:computername
$trace='C:\path\trace.txt'
$Include = @('*.keystore', '*.cer', '*.crt', '*.pfx', '*.jks', '*.ks')
$exclude = '^C:\\(Windows|Program Files|Documents and Settings|Users|ProgramData)|\bBackup\b|\breleases?\b|\bRECYCLE.BIN\b|\bPerfLogs\b|\bold\b|\bBackups\b|\brelease?\b|'

Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\','D:\' -file -Include $include -Recurse -EA 0| 
  Where-Object { $_.DirectoryName -notmatch $exclude } |
  Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName |
  Set-Content -Path $trace 

$des = "C:\some\folder\$remoteserver"
$safe = Get-Content $trace 
$safe | ForEach-Object{
    #find drive-delimeter
    $first=$_.IndexOf(":\");
    if($first -eq 1){
        #stripe it
        $newdes=Join-Path -Path $des -ChildPath @($_.Substring(0,1)+$_.Substring(2))[0]
        }
    else{
        $newdes=Join-Path -Path $des -ChildPath $_
    }
    $folder=Split-Path -Path $newdes -Parent
    $err=0
    #check if folder exists"
    $void=Get-Item $folder -ErrorVariable err  -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if($err.Count -ne 0){
        #create when it doesn't
        $void=New-Item -Path $folder -ItemType Directory -Force -Verbose
        }
    $void=Copy-Item -Path $_ -destination $newdes -Recurse -Container -Verbose
    }
  }
```

**UPDATE**
So I have found out that the file where the lines should be be redirected from the script is not populated, which explains why the next step for copy-item fails. I have tried redirecting in different ways, still cant get it populated. The file is created without issues.

Comment: I noticed that you need to replace the `computername` `$server` with `$_` in the line `$session=new-pssession -computername $_ -credential (Import-Clixml "mycredentials.xml")`

Comment: Why is `${function:getfiles}` defined but never used?

Comment: @MahmoudMoawad I dont know how I missed it, but now the output folder is not created thus the copy fails. SantiagoSquarzon it is a big function to list and filter files and recreate their respectful directories.

Comment: As long as the remote hosts have a folder `"C:\some\folder\...."` and, when copying them to your local session they're not overwritten (the same file name or folder name on all hosts?) then what you're doing should complete properly, aside from the use of the `ForEach-Object` which is not needed

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon The folder in the remote host is created during the execution of ${function:getfiles} . If I explicitly set the remove server name `$session=new-pssession -computername remoteserverName -credential (Import-Clixml "mycredentials.xml") Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock ${function:getfiles} Copy-Item -path "C:\some\folder\SMTH*" -Destination "C:\localfolder" -recurse -FromSession $session` works as expected. I have 400+ servers and need to use the list and foreach-object.

Answer (score 0):

Made a workaround - placed the function in a script which is copied to the remote server / execute it \ clean afterwards.

Comment: I'm glad you got it working!  This should be a comment instead of an answer, though.  There isn't enough detail in it to really help anyone else solve the problem you encountered.  Could you add more detail (such as the enhanced code)?